# Power BI stop sorting by column in matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

In Power BI I have a matrix and I clicked on a column header which made it sort by that column.  I don't want it to because now there's a little triangle on the column header cell.  If I click it again it just resorts ascending/descending.  How do I make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select your visualization -> Click [...] (right top) -> Sort by -> click on column name to deactivate sorting.

Comment: I knew it would be that simple.  Thank you!